# (edited) trying to create a simple lotto game in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to create a simple lotto game in javascript

I'm trying to create a simple small lotto game but using 20 numbers and 4 balls in java script so its ideal to create a random ticket to the user and one as the random lotto numbers with out repeating its self ..... There is a money system involved for every matched number against the random generators the user gets x amount and the numbers light up green.

It should be one click and presto it's all done you either win or lose type of then and a button to play again while the game keeps track of the money won or lost.. any help would be a great help ...

```js
var playcost = 1;
var match1 = 5;
var match2 = 10;
var match3 = 20;
var match4 = 40;
var FirstBall = 0;
var SecondBall = 0;
var ThirdBall = 0;
var ForthBall = 0;

function lottoGen()
{
  setInterval(
          function lottoGen(min , max)
  {
      return Math.round(Math.random() * (20 - 1) + 1);
  }
   function usersNumbers();
  {
      var numbers = [], 
          random;
    
      for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      {   
        
        random = lottoGen(1, 20);
        while(numbers.indexOf(random) !== -1)
        {
            console.log("upps (" + random + ") it is in already.");
            random = lottoGen(1, 20);
            console.log("replaced with: (" + random + ").");
        }
        numbers.push(random);
      }
    output.value = numbers.join(", ");
  }
  btn.onclick = usersNumbers;
  
}
  //Update the scoreboard 
           document.getElementById("lottoGen").innerHTML = "numbers :"+matches;
           document.getElementById("usersNumbers").innerHTML = "numbers  :"+matches;
            
           colourTheTeams(); 
            
           //Tick the clock 
           clockSeconds++;
           document.getElementById("matches").innerHTML = "matches : "+playcost;
          }
    ,1000); 
}

  
  
  
  
  
  
  function colourmatches()
{
 
  if(numbers == usersNumbers)
  {
    document.getElementById("numbers").style.color = "Green";
    document.getElementById("usersNumbers").style.color = "green";
  }
 
  else if(numbers > usersNumbers)
  {
    document.getElementById("numbers").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("usersNumbers").style.color = "black";    
  }
  
  else
  {
    document.getElementById("numbers").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("usersNumbers").style.color = "red";        
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>The Lotto Game</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <H1>The Lotto Game</H1>
    <H1 id="matches">Total :€10</H1>
    <H1 id="FirstBall"> </H1>
    <H1 id="SecondBall"> </H1>
    <H1 id="ThirdBall"> </H1>
    <H1 id="ForthBall"> </H1>
    <div id="randomNumbers"></div>
<H1 id="usersNumbers">your ticket :</H1>
    
<button class="lottoGen">Run the Lottery</button>
<button class="Play-Again">Play Again!</button>

  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: So what is the problem here?

Comment: i cant get it to work and i dont know where i have gone wrong

Comment: I'm no Javascript developer, but from what I see: 1) the brace after `lottoGen`isn't getting closed, 2) the parenthesis after `setIntervall`isn't getting closed, 3) you seem to define `lottoGen()`with no parameters, but call it as `lottoGen(1,20)` with two parameters, 4) you calling `setInterval(func, milliseconds)` without a second parameter, 5) you compare the array `numbers` against the function `userNumbers` instead of it's output: `unumbers=userNumers(); numbers == unumbers`

Comment: Check your js on [JSHint](http://jshint.com). Like @RobinKoch said, there are errors in your code.

Comment: thank you just going through the jsHint now